# Perl: extracting certain values from matrix file

Tags: perl, file, matrix, extract

Given a matrix like text file, I want to extract all the lines (`\t` is the separator) that contain values > 60 in the 3`rd column (pos 2) and values > 80 in the 6 th (pos 5) and send the output to a different file.So far I got:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl;
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

open(my $in, "file.txt")or die $!;
my $line = <$in>;
my $count;
while (<$in>) {
   chomp;
   my @element = split (/\t/,$_);
   if ($element[2] >= 60 && $element[5] > 80){
       $count++; 
   }
}
close $in;
print $count;
```

What is wrong? Thanks.PS. I have found similar questions but my low level Perl skills prevented me from extracting resolve.

Comment: Instead of incrementing $count, you could just do a print "$_\n"; to print out the line to the screen.  That way you can check to see if you are getting the correct lines from your if statement.   If it having issues on the split in which you are not getting a number of elements, you might need to escape the backslash with another backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You forgot to add read mode (`<`) in `open`.
2. Make sure the lines in your file are really tab separated.

Below worked fine for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $in, "<", "file.txt") or die $!;

my $count;

while (<$in>) {
   chomp;
   my @element = split (/\t/,$_);
   if ($element[2] >= 60 && $element[5] > 80){
       $count++; 
   }
}

close $in;
print $count;
```

Where file.txt

```
10  20  60  40  50  90  70  80
10  20  20  40  50  30  70  80
10  20  40  40  50  50  70  80
10  20  65  40  50  80  70  80
10  20  70  40  50  90  70  80
10  20  50  40  50  90  70  80
```

i.e. first and fifth lines of file satisfied the `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

I have copy pasted the code as you just wrote it and I enev replaced the content of the text file but still I get the following error message:

```
Use of uninitialized value $element[2] in numeric ge (>=) at C:\Perl64\Temp1\ex.pl line 12, <$in> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $element[2] in numeric ge (>=) at C:\Perl64\Temp1\ex.pl line 12, <$in> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $element[2] in numeric ge (>=) at C:\Perl64\Temp1\ex.pl line 12, <$in> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $element[2] in numeric ge (>=) at C:\Perl64\Temp1\ex.pl line 12, <$in> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $element[2] in numeric ge (>=) at C:\Perl64\Temp1\ex.pl line 12, <$in> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $element[2] in numeric ge (>=) at C:\Perl64\Temp1\ex.pl line 12, <$in> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $count in print at C:\Perl64\Temp1\ex.pl line 18.
```

Any take on that ?

Comment: Then I think lines in file are not really tab separated.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the file, tab separated and still gives:

```
Use of uninitialized value $count in print at C:\Perl64\Temp1\ex.pl line 19.
```

the line 19 being `print $count;`

Comment: That means the $count was not incremented. That means the if condition did not succeed. Which could be the case if 3rd and 6th column do not have values greater than 60 and 80 respectively. See this demo is working correct: http://ideone.com/evjXgj

Comment: Also please do not keep adding/deleting answers. You could edit your question instead to add more data.

Comment: Indeed, in the recreated file only one condition was true. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about that; my comment was not in the right place and I accidentally deleted something else (I have remedied that). Thanks for the tips. Will do!